# How to split strings inside a numpy array?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have the following table:

As the column 'location' has the state repeating inside it, I am trying to remove the state from location so that it only has the city name.

```
year    location    state   success
2009    New York, NY    NY  1
2009    New York, NY    NY  1
2009    Chicago, IL IL  1
2009    New York, NY    NY  1
2009    Boston, MA  MA  1
2009    Long Beach, CA  CA  1
2009    Atlanta, GA GA  1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
x = KS_clean.column(1)
np.chararray.split(x, ',')
```

How can I split the string so the result only contains the city name like the following:

```
array('New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', ...,)
```

so that I can put it back inside the table?

Sorry it is basic question but I am new to python and still learning. Thanks

Comment: Your data looks like a pandas DataFrame, not a numpy array. Please check.

Comment: It is a pandas DataFrame but when I extract the column (var x) and check its type it says numpy.ndarray

Comment: How did you get the dataframe in the first place? It looks odd. When you select a column, you must get a `Series`, not anything-numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need working with `DataFrame` first (e.g. by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)):

```
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""year;location;state;success
2009;New York, NY;NY;1
2009;New York, NY;NY;1
2009;Chicago, IL;IL;1
2009;New York, NY;NY;1
2009;Boston, MA;MA;1
2009;Long Beach, CA;CA;1
2009;Atlanta, GA;GA;1"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df)
   year        location state  success
0  2009    New York, NY    NY        1
1  2009    New York, NY    NY        1
2  2009     Chicago, IL    IL        1
3  2009    New York, NY    NY        1
4  2009      Boston, MA    MA        1
5  2009  Long Beach, CA    CA        1
6  2009     Atlanta, GA    GA        1
```

Then split by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select first list by `str[0]`:

```
df['location'] = df['location'].str.split(', ').str[0]
print (df)
   year    location state  success
0  2009    New York    NY        1
1  2009    New York    NY        1
2  2009     Chicago    IL        1
3  2009    New York    NY        1
4  2009      Boston    MA        1
5  2009  Long Beach    CA        1
6  2009     Atlanta    GA        1
```

Last if necessary convert by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to numpy array:

```
arr = df.values
print (arr)
[[2009 'New York' 'NY' 1]
 [2009 'New York' 'NY' 1]
 [2009 'Chicago' 'IL' 1]
 [2009 'New York' 'NY' 1]
 [2009 'Boston' 'MA' 1]
 [2009 'Long Beach' 'CA' 1]
 [2009 'Atlanta' 'GA' 1]]
```